# How to increase the sharpness of the image using convolution matrix?

Tags: convolution, image-processing

I am using 3 X 3 convolution matrix to obtain an sharpness image.

[image]

But the output result obtain from the above  matrix is not much sharpen image.
How to increase the sharpness of the image ?

Ya i am using same matrix.

```
common.getPixels(inputPath).then(function () {

sharp(inputPath)
            .png()

.convolve({
           width: 3,
           height: 3, 
           kernel: [0,-1,0,-1,5,-1,0,-1,0]         
          })
```

But the output generated is different.
Need to get more sharpen image than the generated one.

[image]

Comment: Please include a sample of your image. The effectiveness of these filters depend on how sharp and noisy your original image is. An image sample will help others provide help.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are doing something wrong.

Below few lines of matlab code demonstrates the filter kernel you have provided which improves the sharpness of an example image. Note that the kernel is a highpass filter and usually (but not always) highpass filters are used to improve sharpness of typical images...

```
I  = im2double(imread('Cameraman.tif'));
h2 = [0,-1,0;-1,5,-1;0,-1,0];
I2 = conv2(I,h2);
figure,imshow(I);title('original image')
figure,imshow(I2);title('Sharpened image');
```

with the result:

[image]